# PHP object schema validation

Tags: php, json, object, recursion

is it possible to dynamically check if two objects schema is the same (in php)? for example:

```
{
   name: "Name1",
   age: 2,
   kids: [1,3,4]
}

{
   name: "Name2",
   age: 2,
   kids: [1,6,4,3]
}
```

For the above example  I am expecting to return true. Here is another example:

```
{
   name: "Name1",
   age: 2,
   kids: [1,3,4]
}

{
   name: "Name1",
   kids: [1,3,4]
}
```

Here I am expecting to get false (schema not the same: age missing from the second object).

The function definition should look like: `Boolean isSchemaEqual($obj1, $obj2)` (I know there are no function definitions in php, just did it in order to make my question more clear).

**Note:** the schema could be nested, in that I mean some property can hold an object which also needs to be checked against the other object's (same) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to validate multiple levels of schema, you can use recursion in conjunction with an order-less array comparison idiom for the keys.

```
// determines if an array is associative
function isAssociative($array) {
    return (bool)count(array_filter(array_keys($array), 'is_string'));
}

// determines if the keys of two arrays are equal regardless of order
function keysEqual($a, $b) {
    if (!is_array($a) || !is_array($b))
        return false;

    $keysA = array_keys($a);
    $keysB = array_keys($b);

    return array_diff($keysA, $keysB) === array_diff($keysB, $keysA);
}

function isSchemaEqual($a, $b) {
    // validate keys - basic validation
    if (!keysEqual($a, $b))
        return false;

    // if we come across any key where the value is associative and 
    // the schema isn't the same for b's value at $key, then we know 
    // the schemas aren't equal 
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && isAssociative($value) && !isSchemaEqual($value, $b[$key]))
            return false;
    }

    // we couldn't find any differences, so they're equal
    return true;
}
```

You can find some tests, **[here](http://ideone.com/8L8HjD)**.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the keys:

```
if (array_keys($schema1) == array_keys($schema2)) {

}
```

For nested object, you will have to make your own function. One approach would be to make it one-level, with paths like `{kids: {boys: [1,2,3]}}` becoming `kids/boys`, then you can compare the arrays:

```
function flatten_keys($object, $prefix = '') {
   $result = array();
   foreach ($object as $key=>$value) {
     $result[] = $prefix . $key;
     if (is_object($value) || (is_array($value) && array_values($value) != $value) ) {
         $result = array_merge($result, flatten_keys($value, $key .'/'));
     }
   }
   return $result;
}

$a = flatten_keys($schema2);
$b = flatten_keys($schema2);
sort($a);
sort($b);
if ($a == $b){

}
```

Comment: schema1 & schema2 are objects like at the example?

Comment: This is a good solution, however, it only works for the first level of keys assuming @vlio20 wants to validate multiple levels. Additionally, it will fail if the keys are not in the same order.